# How do I store user input into a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have to write a program that prompts for the name, age and salary(String, Int and Float). Which all of them have to be stored into pointer variables. And then output the value and the pointer address. I am not sure on how to store the user input. The >> for the cin has the error 'no operator ">>" matches these operands'. How do I properly store the user input without any errors?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *Age = nullptr;
string *Name = nullptr;
float *Salary = nullptr;
cout << "What is your name? \n";
cin >> *Name;
cout << "Name- " << Name << " Pointer Address- " << &Name << endl;
cout << "What is your age?\n";
cin >> Age;
cout << "Age- " << Age << " Pointer Address- " << &Age << endl;
cout << "What is your salary?\n";
cin >> Salary;
cout << "Salary- " << Salary << " Pointer Address- " << &Salary << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be in page one of the pointers section in any text book or online tutorial.

Comment: The answer is simply: Don't use raw pointers at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *Age = new int;
    string *Name = new string;
    float *Salary = new float;
    cout << "What is your name? \n";
    cin >> *Name;
    cout << "Name- " << *Name << " Pointer Address- " << Name << endl;
    cout << "What is your age?\n";
    cin >> *Age;
    cout << "Age- " << *Age << " Pointer Address- " << Age << endl;
    cout << "What is your salary?\n";
    cin >> *Salary;
    cout << "Salary- " << *Salary << " Pointer Address- " << Salary << endl;
    delete Name;
    delete Age;
    delete Salary;

    return 0;
}
```

1. You want to initialize these pointer first and then read in the value, you can't read into `nullptr`
2. You want to dereference them when you print them out
3. You should delete your pointers once you are done using them

Comment: Though this answers the question, this code never `delete`s the pointers, and thus leaks. (Ideally this would be done with smart pointers)